# Is there some way can accomplish stochastic gradient descent not from scratch

Tags: python, optimization, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

For a standard machine learning problem, e.g, image classification on MNIST, the loss function is fixed, therefor the optimization process can be accomplished simply by calling functions and feed the input into them. There is no need to derive gradients and code the descent procedure by hand.

But now I'm confused when I met some complicated formulation. Say we are solving a semi-supervised problem, and the loss function has two parts:`Ls + lambda * Lu`. The first part is a normal classification formulation, e.g, cross entropy loss. And the second part varies. In my situation, `Lu` is a matrix factorization loss, which in specific is:`Lu = MF(D, C * W)`. And the total loss function can be written as:

`L = \sum log p(yi|xi) + MF(D, C * W) 
= \sum log p(yi|Wi) + MF(D, C * W)
= \sum log p(yi|T * Wi + b) + MF(D, C * W)`

Where parameters are `W, C, T` and `b`. The first part is a classification loss, and the input `xi` is a raw of `W`, i.e. `Wi`, a vector of size `(d, 1)`. And the label `yi` can be a one-hot vector of size `(c, 1)`, so parameters `T` and `b` map the input to the label size. And the second part is a matrix factorization loss.

Now I'm confused when I'm going to optimize this function using sgd. It can be solved by write down the formulation derive gradients then accomplish a training procedure from scratch. But I'm wondering if there is a simpler way? Because it's easy to use a deep learning tool like Tensorflow or Keras to train a classification model, all u need to do is build a network and feed the data.

So similarly, is there a tool that can automatically compute gradients after I defined the loss function? Because deriving gradients and achieve them from scratch is really annoying. Both the classification loss and matrix factorization loss is very common, so I think the combination can be achieved thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theano and Tensorflow will exactly do this for you if you can formulate your optimization-problem within their framework / language. These frameworks are also general enough to implement non-NN-based algorithms, like simple first-order-based optimizations like yours.

If that's not possible you can try [autograd](https://github.com/HIPS/autograd), which can do this on a subset of numpy. Just formulate your loss as numpy-function (while sticking to supported functions; read the docs) and let autograd build the gradients.

Keep in mind, that the somewhat by-construction-approach used by Theano & Tensorflow will be more efficient (because of the more defined input and because these two libraries are a bit more evolved).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm reading Tensorflow's handbook cause I haven't use it before. I'll ask if I meet other problems. Thanks for ur advice. And one more question, do I need to derive gradients? Or I just need to formulate the loss function?

Answer (score 0):

Both Theano & Tensorflow have built-in differentiation for you. So you only need to form the loss.